# NCover Subscription - is it worth paying the money for it?

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, ncover

I just have a quick question in relation to the NCover software. NCover is an awesome tool but I do not have any historical experience with it to justify to my manager if buying the subscription is worth it? NCover complete subscription is almost $200!

Comment: How can you be sure it's awesome if you have no historical experience?

Comment: Also look at TestDriven.net as I think it includes a copy of NCover

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains have released a similar tool DotCoverhttp://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/buy/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try it out. It offers the complete package in Academic license. You can show it off to your manager and let him decide if it provides enough productivity for your org to go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try it out with the 21-day free trial: http://www.ncover.com/trial

Evaluate if it's worth the $200..

Answer (score 0):

While each potential user must decide what makes the most sense for them and their organization, we just wanted to clarify what is included in a subscription.  Our current subscription includes support, all big fixes, and point releases. Most importantly, it also includes access to the next major version. We have a major new release planned. Purchasing the subscription now would entitle you to that new release when it becomes available.  Currently the majority of our customers buy a subscription.